# Method to Check Password in Java Not Working

Tags: java, passwords

I'm trying to write a method that returns if the string is or isn't a valid password in CodeHS.

It needs to be at least eight characters long and can only have letters and digits.

In the grader, it passes every test except for `passwordCheck("codingisawesome")` and `passwordCheck("QWERTYUIOP")`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public boolean passwordCheck(String password)
{
    if (password.length() < 8)
    {
        return false;  
    }
    else 
    {  
        char c;  
        int count = 0;   
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) 
        {
            c = password.charAt(i);  
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) 
            {
                return false;  
            } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) 
            {
                count++;     
            }
        }
        if (count < 2)
        {  
            return false;  
        }
    }
    return true;  
}
```

If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you **certain** about those requirements? Nothing about uppercase and lowercase letter(s)?

Comment: You are checking if password has at least two digits. "It needs to be at least eight characters long and can only have letters and digits" has no such requirement. By this specification, both of those passwords should be valid, but you are refusing them because they don't have enough digits for your taste.

Comment: from your code it looks like you have a requirement of having at least 2 digits, but you haven't mentioned that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your requirement is as stated

> It needs to be at least eight characters long and can only have letters and digits

Then there is no need to count digits. Simply check that the password is the minimum length, then loop over every character returning false if any are not a letter or digit. Like,

```
public boolean passwordCheck(String password) {
    if (password != null && password.length() >= 8) {
        for (char ch : password.toCharArray()) {
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try an approach using patterns (this is simpler than looping):

```
public boolean passwordCheck(String password)
{
    return password!=null && password.length()>=8 && password.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]*");
}
```

Decent tutorial on regular expressions (that's where the A-Z magic comes from): http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: @Kartik True, I added it.

Answer (score 1):

It's failing those tests because your code checks that the password must have at least 2 digits:-

> ```
> if (count < 2)
> {  
>     return false;  
> }
> ```

And your test strings don't have any. Remove this piece of code and it should work. For a better way of doing it, see other answers.